# How to reverse-engineer and convert a protected EX4 file to MQL4-source in an MQ4 file?

Tags: mql4, metatrader4

I have a few **`.EX4`**-files which are protected / encrypted.

I want to decompile them to `MQL4`-source-code files in an **`.MQ4`** format.

Is there any direct solution for this?